# Port tunneling (other than ssh, e. gr. no-ip)

Tags: email, networking, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

Network policies at my workplace (a University outside the US) are rather inconsistent. While every port other than 80 and 443 is blocked, no websites are restricted (at least for professors). Gmail/pop and smtp sockets are open as an exception to the rule (which makes both me and the Dean think there is no particular policy against personal e-mail).

I'm faculty at this University, but also teach at a different one, for which I use a university-specific, non-gmail e-mail address. I have all of my e-mail history in Outlook, however, as you can suspect I can access *that* alternative e-mail address through webmail but not through smtp/pop/imap from my workplace. We asked the sockets to be open but have been given no response by the IT guys in more than a month.

I've been considering port tunneling, but haven't access (right now) to a server with ports 80 and 443 to ssh-tunnel through. I know I *could* use one port at home to tunnel either the incoming or the outgoing e-mail. But I think it's too power consumming for just half the job.

Is there a way I can do the tunneling with the help of some free service like no-ip, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the best solution I've found is to ssh-tunnel the *imap* socket. This way, I can get both incoming **and** outgoing mail through one tunnel. I plan to wake-on-lan and hybernate my home server in order to save power.